# Changing Context Menu in React Based on Selected Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an editor in which I'd like to have a context menu (an anchored menu, not a pop-up) that changes depending upon the selected item: e.g. when I'm editing item one, I get the context menu for item one, and when I'm editing item two, I get the context menu for item two.

```
+----------+ +------------------+
|          | |     Item One     |
|  Editor  | +------------------+
|   Menu   | +------------------+
|          | |     Item Two     |
+----------+ +------------------+
```

I'm not sure what the most React-y way to do this would be. My instinct would be to have a component hierarchy like this (describing children):

```
EditorInterface
    - [EditableOne, EditableTwo, ...]
    - ContextMenu
```

and then pass an `onFocus` callback to `EditableOne` et al., but then I'm not sure how to update the `EditorMenu` component based on that. Maybe this isn't the right way to go about this at all.

The `EditorMenu` component needs to be able to talk to the `Item` components as well (to signal changes), which suggests that the `EditorMenu` should be a child component of the `Item` (since all the state associated with aforementioned `Item` should be maintained in the `Item` and solely there).

Tips appreciated!

Comment: The context menu and the editable items should all share the same parent. The parent should keep track of what item is currently being edited. Your context menu should use this state to change it's form or whatever you plan on putting in there. The parent should also contain an array of all children items, so that your context menu can pass an index and new data to replace the item in the parents items state array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are developing in React, the `Parent` will control its `Child`, so you should always be [lifting your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Also, take a look at [thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html), it might help with architecting your React app.

Your hierarchy should look like this:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class EditorInterface extends Component {
  state = {
    focusedItem: 0
  }

  handleItemFocus = item =>
    this.setState({focusedItem: item});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ContextMenu focusedItem={this.state.focusedItem} />
        <EditableOne onItemFocus={this.handleItemFocus} />
        <EditableTwo onItemFocus={this.handleItemFocus} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ContextMenu = ({ focusedItem }) =>
  focusedItem === 1 ? (
    <div>
      <span>Context Menu for Item 1</span>
    </div>
  ) : focusedItem === 2 ? (
    <div>
      <span>Context Menu for Item 2</span>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <span>No item is focused</span>
    </div>
  );

const EditableOne = ({onItemFocus}) => (
  <input type="text" onFocus={() => onItemFocus(1)} />
)

const EditableTwo = ({onItemFocus}) => (
  <input type="text" onFocus={() => onItemFocus(2)} />
)
```